# First Child ignores width and height

Tags: html, css, angular, web

I have a really simple angular project with html and scss code. In a container I have 2 objects that I position using flexbox. Everything worked fine with the second object, but the first one just does not work.

Heres my HTML:

```
<div class="Player">
    <p id="Player"> Test </p>
        <input class="lineTwo">
        <button class="lineTwo">Test</button>
</div>
```

and heres my scss:

```
.Player {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    p {
        border: 1px solid rgba($color: #000000, $alpha: 0.3);
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 16px;
        height: 500px;
    }

.lineTwo {
        font-size: 15px;
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        &:first-child {
            left: 0;
            width: 50%;
        }
        &:last-child {
            right: 0;
            justify-content: center;
            width: 50%;
        }
    }
}
```

I want both the Input and the button to have a width, but I do not want both to have the same with.
If I write it like this:

```
.lineTwo {
        font-size: 15px;
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        &:first-child {
            left: 0;
        }
        &:last-child {
            right: 0;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    }
}
```

...it works just fine and both have a width of 50%, of their parent (except the input is a little bit wider, if you know a solution for this I also appreciate the help).

As I said I dont want both to have the same width so I tried it with the first code but the first child (the Input) does not change. The weird thing is that the button works just fine and if I give him a value like this: `width: 75%;` it works.

There is no error and I also can not change the height of the Input. It feels like I can't change him at all. If I give the input another tag and try to use this tag with .tag for the &:first-child, still no change.

I am sorry if there are any mistakes in my text I am not a native speaker and thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm more familiar with native CSS then SCSS yet from my point of view, The input is not the `first-child`, it's the `p` try using `first-of-type` or simply add another class to distinguish it

About the `except the input is a little bit wider` make sure to use `box-sizing: border-box` so the width includes the padding

Comment: It is still not working. I think the input is the first child cause the `p` does not have the class `lineTwo`. I tried it with  `input:first-of-type` I do not know if I did this correct cause its the first time I work with `first-of-type`  so if it was wrong please correct me. But it still did not work. Do you have any other ideas?

For the `except the input is a little bit wider` part you were 
completely right so thank you for that.

Thank you anyway for your help.

Comment: @Palaeonton the input is definitely not first-child. `p` is the first child. Here are some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: @CornelRaiu ok, your right my bad. I just fixed it thank you. I wrote `&:nth-child(2)'`and it worked.

Comment: @CornelRaiu May you explain to me, why the first child is from the `.Player` class and not only from `.lineTwo` please?

Comment: @Palaeonton because `:first-child` doesn't look at classes/ids. It gets the first child of any type.